# How to pull bank statements from websites?

Tags: banking, onlinebanking, ofx

I need to pull bank account statements from a number of different sources. I'd love to be able to get this data in some sort of standardized fashion, be it CSV or OFX or XML or whatever. I just need to be able to get this data. I'll be using my own account to grab transactions from, so there shouldn't be too many 'legal' problems there. How do sites like Mint.com get bank statements? They simply ask for your account information, the URL, and then they're off and running. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write a screen scraper in your favorite language to do it.  Automate it away.

Normally banks give you access up to three months of transactions via their online services.

Don't forget to make it push the panic button when the screen scraping fails.

The main point here is to automate it so that the pain (of running it manually) goes away so that all you see are "constantly" updated transactions of your accounts.

Comment: I'm completely new to screen scraping. I'm writing my application in Python, any idea on where to start, module-wise? I found Bankjob (a Ruby scraper), but I really need it in Python. My bank does support exporting transactions to OFX, but there's not specifically a way to automate it other than via scraping. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at beautiful soup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/. It's pretty decent.

Comment: How do you write a screen scraper that will deal with the fact that some banks have complicated javascript that runs during the login process and the need to run the scraper from the command line without a GUI?

Comment: Nowadays we can run webkit headless with JavaScript engine and all. Check out [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: I believe scraping is the way to go (in the absence of direct feeds). I have created a project for parsing HTML tables of financial transactions: https://github.com/bunsn/boiler. To add support for your own bank, you write a basic “statement definition”. It doesn’t handle logging in or crawling multiple statements but may be useful as part of a scraping tool.

Comment: holygeek, @DomChristie: How do you actually download the *statements* (PDFs) using something like PhantomJS? Doesn't PhantomJS completely fail at *downloading*?

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in a simple, personal solution, one easy way would have Mint aggregate all your purchases and use an existing scraper to download them. Something like this: https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi.

Answer (score 2):

The other main things you may consider is [Plaid](https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#step-2-simple-integration) (more commercial product but looks really good) And https://www.buxfer.com which has a free api. Mint as of late has made it harder for scrapers to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

Grab your transactions and save them to CSV of XLS to convert to OFX and / QIF using [iCreateOFX Basic v4](http://icreateofx.co.uk/basic.php) or try the [v5 beta](http://icreateofx.co.uk/basicv5.php).

Answer (score -1):

I read a comprehensive technical article on this awhile ago, however, I can't find it. From my memory this is what mint does to get data from your bank:

1. Query API from this company: http://www.finappstore.com/
2. If bank isn't in above API they fallback to screen scraping

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to how that website helps out any. Do they have an API for getting statements? ie: is it worth my time to register with them? ;)

Comment: I thought that the finappstore API is only available from flex through their code/protocol.

Comment: This website is dead